# Extjs xml reader not working

Tags: extjs, xmlreader

I have the following XML Configuration...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="IncidentMgt">
<EntityType Name="in">
<Property Name="persistent_id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="30"/>
<Property Name="active_f" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="add_property_persids" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="add_workflow_persids" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="at">
<Property Name="persistent_id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="30"/>
<Property Name="active_f" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="add_property_persids" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="add_workflow_persids" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
</EntityType>
</Schema>
```

Following is my XML Reader configuration:

```
reader : {
            type : 'xml',
            record : 'Property',
            rootProperty: 'EntityType',

        }
```

My Model :

> fields: [{name:'Name',mapping:'@Name'}]

I am facing problem in loading  the store.... could you let me know where is the mistake/where should i change to make this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the rest of the code, I can't tell you the error.

Here is a [working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/onc) using the data you provided.

Compare it with your code, maybe you can find the problem.

Comment: thank you ... this worked ..... :) but to clarify more on  my requirement.... I need  to have" <EntityType Name="in">" can be filtered in the store ..... so we need to change model configuration here..    any idea here ....

Comment: I've never filtered data using a hidden column or store field that doesn't exists on the grid. 

What I've used, and I believe is a more elegant solution is grouping by certain columns. Check this link http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#grouped-grid